# What is more costly? Instantiating an Advanced Data Structure or performing a couple of loops (one after the other O(n)) and using arrays?

Tags: java, optimization

I was tasked to create an algorithm to solve a given problem but was also instructed to give the most optimal solution with regards to time and memory. I will be given an array of Strings. Ultimately I want to get all the characters of all the strings of the array in a char[].

My question to you (especially to those who have dealt with code and performance optimisation) is should I use `List<char>` then manually destroy the object and copy the contents into a char[] or do I do it manually and working only with arrays (which I am also unsure of how to do.). Is the cost of instantiating a List<> object greater than looping through the String[], converting each string to char[] and them merging all char[] arrays together?

EDIT:

Okay, let me be more precise then. Is it better to convert all strings of a String[] into a List<> or any other abstract data structure and work with that or do the following: looping through the String[], converting each string to char[] and them merging all char[] arrays together?

Comment: I wouldn't call a list an "advanced" data structure. But the answer is: why don't you try?

Comment: Why not insert all the characters into a hashset?  that will get you all characters of all strings.

Comment: but the is my question.. Which one is more efficient. Using hashtags or doing everywith with arrays? The creation and maintenance of hashtags dont come cheap..

Comment: You don't need to create and destroy, just literally loop over all of your strings inserting into 1 HashSet, which will be very efficient

Comment: what is the complexity for a search in a Hashset?

Comment: It's a constant time lookup, O(1), though in practice its a small constant

Comment: Thank you buddha! Move your answer/recommandation from the comment section to the answer section, I'll mark it as correct and you'll get an upvote!

Comment: What do HashSets have to do with the question?

Comment: well.. seeing how a simple search in a hashset has O(1) complexity, that answers my question.. The only reason I was willing to work with arrays was that the lookup is just a small constant.. did not know that was the case with hashsets aswell

Comment: The question isn't clear. If input is `["a", "the", "he"]` are you expecting `['a','t','h','e']` or are you expecting `['a','t','h','e','h','e']`?  If the first then the hashset is a reasonable solution.

Comment: It's not *actually* O(1) - that's the average efficiency with a reasonable load factor. Worst case is still O(n)

Comment: @digitaljoel, oh no.. I'm afraid I need duplicates.. I will be needing all the characters from all the strings

Comment: You need duplicates? Why not just append all of the strings together then in a buffer? Use StringBuilder and just append everything together

Comment: @Dragan - your description of your problem is unnecessarily obtuse and obfuscated.  What you are really asking is for the fastest way to concatenate an array of strings to form an array of characters.  You are NOT "merging".  You are "concatenating".  You will get much better answers, and quicker if you use the correct (English) CS terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need dpulicates then really you are just appending all of the strings together. In this case why not use a String buffer.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : myStringArray){
    sb.append(s);
}
char chars[] = sb.toString().toCharArray();
```

The StringBuilder can be created with an initial capacity as well to avoid the cost of dynamic resizing. This won't be as fast as allocating a char[] and directly inserting chars but should be fast enough for most uses. As another alternative check out [CharBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html), which is backed by a char[].

Comment: isn't using buffer real expensive though.. I think buffering the characters is an overkill

Comment: First write working application and then start optimizing. You'll never create perfectly optimized application at first go

Comment: And also, using a StringBuilder is not "real expensive" if you preallocate it the right size.

Comment: Stephen is right about this, almost all of the java collections, and the StringBuilder, can be preallocated with a certain "capacity" for extra efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that what you are really trying to do is to concatenate the strings (i.e. join them end to end) to form a character array.

This is probably the most memory efficient way of doing this:

```
int size = 0;
for (String s : strings) { size += s.length(); }
char[] result = new char[size];
int i = 0;
for (String s : strings) {
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
        result[i++] = s.charAt(j);
    }
}
```

If you are trying to minimize memory allocation and/or copying, I wouldn't recommend using `String.toCharArray()`, or `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for ( String s : strings ) {
    charList.addAll(s.toCharArray());
}
return charList.toArray(Character.class);
```

or something like that.

Comment: is your solution more efficient than greedybuddha's?

Comment: my code is titled "pseudocode" it just looks a lot like java :). I don't know if it would be faster than greedybuddha's or not, you should try them both and find out. Unless you are expecting a very large array of strings I doubt you will see much difference.